# PhysX3 with MinGW - linking error

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, physx

I'm trying to compile a PhysX [sample](http://mmmovania.blogspot.de/2011/05/getting-started-with-physx-3.html) using MinGW but I'm getting these errors:

```
undefined reference to `physx::PxProfileZoneManager::createProfileZoneManager(physx::PxFoundation*)'
undefined reference to `physx::PxDefaultErrorCallback::~PxDefaultErrorCallback()'
undefined reference to `physx::PxDefaultErrorCallback::PxDefaultErrorCallback()'
```

My compile command:

```
g++.exe -o Test.exe Test.cpp -Iinc -Llib -lPhysX3Common_x86 -lPhysX3_x86 -lPhysX3Extensions -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lPhysX3Extensions -lglu32
```

Now my question is: in what .lib file(s) are these methods stored?

Answer (score 2):

The createProfileZoneManager() symbol should be in **PhysXProfileSDK.lib**.

The PxDefaultErrorCallback() constructor and destructor symbols really should be in **PhysX3Extensions.lib**.  Your compile command already lists the lib twice, though that should not be an issue.